# How to use AOP annotation inside method not in method level

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I am using Spring AOP to log the DB execution time, but it is applying to the entire method execution time.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TrackExecutionTime {

}

Is there any possibility that we can use this @TrackExecutionTime not in the method level but inside a method just above some statement like below - 

@TrackExecutionTime
List<Release> releaseList = releaseRepo.findByProductName(productName.toUpperCase());
```

that way I can able to get only the DB execution time not only the entire method execution time, as my method contains other business logic too which also including if we use the AOP annotation at the method level.

Answer (score 0):

Spring AOP default configuration uses proxies to execute the aspect hence only methods can be annotated.

A bit of a detour on the proxies. A proxy wraps a target method so when you call a method elsewhere Spring makes sure to invoke the method on the proxy and that invocation then contains the aspect code which gets executed before, after, around the call itself (depending on the aspect). There can be several proxies wrapping a single class.

Then an option is to add your aspect annotation to the repository method.

If we need to track the execution time only for subset of calls to the method (which sounds a bit strange a requirement) then we can add a wrapper method - say make a Spring-managed Metrics class with a said time tracking method that accepts a lambda and is annotated with the `@TrackExecutionTime`. The original call would then be something like

```
metrics.executeTimed(() -> releaseRepo.findByProductName(productName.toUpperCase()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not AOP-specific, because annotations are a Java language feature. The answer is: Annotations on arbitrary lines of code are not part of the Java language concept, which for you means you also cannot use them for AOP purposes. This is simply a Java limitation. Neither Spring AOP nor native AspectJ can support a feature which does not exist in Java to begin with.

Friendly suggestion: Please learn more about Java first, then get acquainted with some basic software design and clean code principles. Finally, you shall be able to achieve what you want, albeit in a different way from what you just dreamed up here.